# Where are the meta-accounts of a user listed?

Tags: support

When I look at the accounts listed at a "users"-page, I do not see any of the meta accounts (not even when on **meta**.tex.stackexchange.com, at my *own* users-page, and choosing "view more"). While meta does not have its own reputation but inherits it from the main page, the "last seen", "badges", "questions", and "answers" are meta-specific. Where can I find the meta-accounts-list? If there is no such list: Why not?

(**If** there is no such list and there is no good reason against it, the tag would be *feature-request*.)

Comment: You mean in the list of accounts like http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/6865/stephen?tab=accounts? There the meta-accounts are not listed, except for http://meta.stackexchange.com, which is a site in its own right. It's true, that the badges are meta specific and actually should be listed there as well. I don't think there is an extra list for them.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes, like http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/users/6865/stephen?tab=accounts It is not only badges, but "last seen", number of "questions", and number of "answers", too. Well, as there is no such list (please post your comment as answer!), I requested it at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117573/171937.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an account on a main site, you have an "implicit" account on the meta site. However, if you have never participated on a meta, your meta account won't exist quite yet.

But the intent is for the meta account to be assumed, with the caveat that not everyone makes it over to meta (or needs to).